# Inconsistent Accessibility on field types in C#

Tags: c#, types, field

I'm trying to make a few simple classes for my program and I'm being stumped by the inconsistent accessibility on field types error for my Tile[,] class 'theGrid' object. I've had a look at a few of the other solutions and set everything to public as I can see but I'm still stuck as to what to do with this.

Could you tell me how to fix this?

```
public class Level
{
    public Tile[,] theGrid;
    public Tile[,] TheGrid
    {
        get { return theGrid; }
        set { theGrid = value;}
    }

    public static Tile[,] BuildGrid(int sizeX, int sizeY)
    {
        Tile earth = new Tile("Earth", "Bare Earth. Easily traversable.", ' ', true);
        //this.createTerrain();

        for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
            {
                theGrid[x, y] = earth;
            }
        }
        return theGrid;
    }
```

And here's a shortened version of the tile class:

```
public class Tile
{
    //all properties were set to public

    public Tile()
    {
        mineable = false;
        symbol = ' ';
        traversable = true;
        resources = new List<Resource>();
        customRules = new List<Rule>();
        name = "default tile";
        description = "A blank tile";
        area = "";
    }

    public Tile(string tName, string tDescription, char tSymbol, bool tTraversable)
    {
        resources = new List<Resource>();
        customRules = new List<Rule>();
        area = "";
        symbol = tSymbol;
        this.traversable = tTraversable;
        this.name = tName;
        this.description = tDescription;

        mineable = false;
    }

    public void setArea(string area)
    {
        this.area = area;
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help you could give me with this one.

Comment: Can you show the properties/fields of your `Tile` class?

Answer (score 2):

Static methods can only access static members.

You need to create new  array of tiles

```
 public static Tile[,] BuildGrid(int sizeX, int sizeY)         
 {              
      Tile[,] theGrid = new Tile[sizeX, sizeY];

      .... the rest of the code is the same
 }
```

Comment: This. A static method can't access any instance member variables - think of it as "a method you could call from anywhere without previously creating (new-ing) the thing that's containing it"

Comment: How is it different from what I said?

Comment: Except that using a non-static member produces another error message. (object reference required).

Comment: @Henk Holterman In my code theGrid is just a local variable, not a field

Answer (score 1):

The exact error message indicates that the accessibility of `Tile` is less than public.
But in you listing of `Tile` it is public.

Possible causes

- one of the other types, `Resource` or `Rule` is declared internal (ie without `public`)
- you have another `Tile` class
- the posted code for `public class Tile` is incorrect.
- the error message is quoted incorrectly